# Implementing Javascript variables into jQuery Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to implement a for loop into my Javascript/jQuery code, which I **know** works since I did the testing before I implemented the for loop. I found the for loop syntax off of this website: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp I am not sure how to implement my variable "i" into my for loop within the .css jQuery method. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
for(var i=0;i<36;i++) {
    $(".quote_" + i).mouseenter(function(){
        $("td.quote_" + i).css("background-color", "rgb(238, 238, 238)");
    });
    $(".quote_" + i).mouseleave(function(){
        $("td.quote_" + i).css("background-color", "white");
    });
}
```

This is the code which I **know** works:

```
$(".quote_1").mouseenter(function(){
        $("td.quote1").css("background-color", "rgb(238, 238, 238)");
    });
    $(".quote_1").mouseleave(function(){
        $("td.quote_1").css("background-color", "white");
    });
```

Comment: Just so you know I **did** include a jQuery library, so yes, jQuery runs.

Comment: wrong approach, no need to for loop it, with a class of quote, jquery will do the loop for you as long as you bind the mouse event on quote. Or you can just use css for the hover effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem of using a [closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
for(var i=0;i<36;i++) {
    $(".quote_" + i).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(238, 238, 238)");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
}
```

Instead of creating a loop like this, I would recommend adding an additional class called `quote` or something like that to each of these elements so that the elements class attribute will look like `class="quote quote_1"` then

```
    $(".quote").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(238, 238, 238)");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used your second example, which worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

This is all wrong.

Use *one* CSS class instead of numbering them. Then use CSS. No JavaScript required.

```
.quote {
    background-color: white;
}
.quote:hover {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
```

Comment: Good job making me think of CSS. It turns out, the main reason my code wasn't working was because I had conflicting CSS in my Stylesheet.

Comment: Whilst you *can* do this in JavaScript, it will perform rather poorly, especially with many elements. I strongly recommend doing style changes in response to mouse move events via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question come up a lot. It has to do with how the value of `i` is bound, or more specifically how it's not.

Google for "js closures loop" and you'll find answers covering this.

http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)